# WP_Query to work with custom view

Tags: posts, wp-query, wpdb

I have created a [Database `VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) on `wp_posts` which selects its all columns and exposes an extra calculated columns (average). So my View is *identical* to `wp_posts` plus one column, which I want to use for sorting at later stage.

- Is there a way to bind `WP_Query` to that view?
- In general, is it possible to bind `WP_Query` to a custom table, which has all the mandatory columns of `WP_Query`?

I am able to get records with `$wpdb->get_results( _custom_query_here_ )`, but that doesn't let me use `WP_Query` features.

P.S.: I thought `WP_Query::parse()` is the answer to my curiosity, but apparently not.

**EDIT**

Here is the VIEW query:

```
CREATE VIEW `calculated_posts`
AS 
  SELECT *, 
         (SELECT Avg(CAST(`meta_value` as SIGNED))
          FROM   `wp_commentmeta` 
          WHERE  meta_key = 'rating' 
                 AND comment_id IN (SELECT comment_id 
                                    FROM   wp_comments 
                                    WHERE  comment_post_id = ID)) AS 
            rating_average 
  FROM   wp_posts;
```

**Edit 2:**

From the solution provided by @birgire here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-table-name-and-make-wordpress-still-working, I used the following code:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->posts = 'calculated_posts';
```

The WP_Query runs successfully, but I can't access the field `rating_average`.

Comment: Would you mind to show how you created the View? (My)SQL Views aren't that commonly used, so it might help. Also please show us the fully `WP_Query` incl. arguments as this _might_ be important.

Comment: @Kaiser, I have updated my post with VIEW's code.

Answer (score 4):

### Use a custom *view* in the front-end:

You can try to modify the `SELECT` queries in the front-end with the following (alpha) plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: wpdb - a custom SELECT view for the wp_posts table on the front-end
 * Version:     alpha
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'query', function( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $view = 'calculated_posts'; // <-- Edit to your needs.
    if( 'select' === mb_substr( strtolower( $query ) , 0, 6 ) )
        if( false !== mb_stripos( $query, $wpdb->posts ) )
            $query = str_ireplace( $wpdb->posts, $view, $query );

    return $query;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

by using the `query` filter of the `wpdb` class.

We don't want to modify the `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries.

This will only affect queries made from the native `wpdb` class, but not for example direct *MySQLi* calls.

Notice that there's of course the possibility that plugins and themes can bybass the native `wpdb` class when connecting to the database.

There might also be examples of more complex queries, e.g. combination of SELECT and INSERT. The above plugin could be modified to adjust for these cases.

**Notice**: Remember to take a backup before trying.

### Accessing the extra field of the custom view:

The extra `rating_average` field should now be available in the `WP_Post` instance, like:

```
$post->rating_average
```

We can also create a custom template tag:

```
function get_the_rating_average()   
{
    $post = get_post();
    return ! empty( $post ) ? $post->rating_average : false;
}
```

Here I'm just modifying the structure of the `get_the_ID()` function.

The corresponding display function is:

```
function the_rating_average()   
{
    echo get_the_rating_average();
}
```

We can now easily access the extra field in the loop:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '5' ) );
while( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_rating_average();  #<-- displaying our extra field here
endwhile;
```

We also better use a name for our extra field that's not already in use by the default fields.

Comment: Would this change be permanent and does it has drawbacks (like any effect on insert / update)? Where should I put this code and what would be the scope of change?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can try this as your own plugin. Take a backup and then create for example the file `/custom-view/custom-view.php` inside your `/wp-content/plugins/` directory and activate.

Comment: Birgire, the plugin probably won't work. It will fire before `plugins_loaded` and `is_admin()` won't be set there. I know, that you know, that it should be wrapped in a callback hooked to `admin_init` or a similar hook. :)

Comment: @kaiser thanks, I'm probably to sleepy to recall anything correctly ;-) but I think is_admin() worked even after taking it outside into the global scope, will try it out after a good sleep ;-)

Comment: Thank @birgire. Actually the last code worked with WP_Query, which I wanted. But I can't access the field name `rating_average`. Do I have to register the column somewhere, so WP_Query don't hide it?

Comment: Great to hear it works for you. I updated the answer, to explain how you can access it. @kaiser amazingly it looks like it's working for her ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help @birgire. Sorry I am kind of n00b with WordPress internals. Can you tell how to add filed to WP_Post instance you mentioned?

Comment: When you have `SELECT * FROM calculated_posts ...` type of queries, your extra field should be part of the returned `WP_Post` objects from the `WP_Query`, as far as I understand it.

Comment: I have updated my question above: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167174/37918.

Comment: aha, don't use this part in your edit 2, it will not target the SELECT queries only. Just use the code in the current answer, I just checked and it worked on my install.

Comment: @kaiser `is_admin()` is available very very early. The function is defined in `load.php`, absolutely the 1st file loaded by [`wp-settings.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L21). Regarding the constant it checks, it's defined even earlier, on the [1st line of `wp-admin/admin.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin.php#L15), the admin bootstrap file.